# Using apache proxypass to redirect to /blog (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, apache, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I'm running a ReactJS app at https://www.hackachieve.com with the following structure:

Port 80/443: Front-end - ReactJS SPA
Port: 8000 - Back-end - django rest framework API

I've installed wordpress properly at /var/www/html and I'm trying to redirect the user from /blog to it.

The issue is that my proxy pass is not working. What happens when the user tries to reach https://www.hackachieve.com/blog is that its redirected back to the main page /. I've found a 301 redirect by inspecting the devtools.

/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName hackachieve.com
    ServerAlias www.hackachieve.com
    ServerAdmin joaopaulofurtado@live.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/hackachieve-frontend

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5000/

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =hackachieve.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.hackachieve.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName hackachieve.com
    ServerAlias www.hackachieve.com
    ServerAdmin joaopaulofurtado@live.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/hackachieve-frontend


   ProxyPreserveHost On

   ProxyPass / http://localhost:5000/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5000/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-frontend.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-frontend.log combined

    RewriteEngine off
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.hackachieve.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =hackachieve.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

    SSLEngine on
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf


SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/hackachieve.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/hackachieve.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>




<VirtualHost *:8000>

    ServerName hackachieve.com
    ServerAlias www.hackachieve.com
    ServerAdmin joaopaulofurtado@live.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/hackachieve-backend
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-backend.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-backend.log combined


 Alias /static /var/www/hackachieve-backend/static
    <Directory /var/www/hackachieve-backend/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/hackachieve-backend/hackachieve>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

WSGIPassAuthorization On
    WSGIDaemonProcess hackachieve python-home=/var/www/hackachieve-backend/venv python-path=/var/www/hackachieve-backend
    WSGIProcessGroup hackachieve
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/hackachieve-backend/hackachieve/wsgi.py

SSLEngine on
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/hackachieve.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/hackachieve.com/privkey.pem



</VirtualHost>
```

I expect that when the user reaches https://www.hackachieve.com/blog he gets redirected to my Wordpress blog.

I don't want to ReactJS to handle this route